# Prestashop 1.6.12 Attachment File Upload failing on larger files

Tags: php, prestashop-1.6

I have a Prestashop 1.6.12 and need to upload a file attachment. This works fine for small files (under 8MB) but not for larger ones. I increased the size in Administration > Preferences > Max size for attachment and in php.ini - but still nothing.

The strange thing is that it doesn't throw an error that the size is too big (if I put the limit to 1MB and upload a 2MB file, at the end of the upload it throws this error), but for larger files it just starts the upload and stops on 4% or 5% and just stands there (doesn't show any errors).

Did anyone have this issue? How can I debug further?

Answer (score 0):

It was a limit on post_max_size in php.ini, have increased that and now it's fine.